# Support CommonMark fenced code blocks

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting, markdown

It would be great to add support for [fenced code blocks as defined in the CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.17/#fenced-code-blocks):

- it would be consistent with GitHub code blocks
- it would be much more practical to type, instead of having to indent every line which is a pain…
- it would allow to define explicitly (and easily) a language for a code block

Comment: I'm not sure if only cherry picking is wise given the fact that they might [implement CommonMark all the way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se)

Comment: @rene ah right it's on meta.stackexchange that's why I didn't find an actual discussion about that. Yeah I support that, however in the meantime that would be great to improve that part as it's (for me) a huge deal. I end up contributing on stack overflow much less because of that detail… Maybe I'm too spoiled by github.

Comment: As a workaround for now: Indenting lines can be done by (a) using a code editor, (b) selecting the text and pressing Ctrl+K, (c) selecting the text and pressing the "code" button on the menu bar. Don't let the lack of fenced code blocks put you off contributing!

Comment: This would be awesome. Dealing with the extra level of indentation is extra confusing for new users and a hassle for everyone else. Yes, cherry pick it, get it deployed yesterday.

Comment: I agree that it's silly that this feature gets blocked because someday we *might* have "CommonMark all the way". I don't contribute to StackOverflow as much now because of that…

Comment: Very much agree. It's a pain to add lines to the way current code is.

Comment: This feature request is detailed at [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-markdown-code-blocks).

Comment: I don’t care if this is implemented with CommonMark or not. All I care about is all the Python questions which are indecipherable because somebody (usually but not always new to the site) got confused by the indentation requirements. I care about the other languages too, but it’s particularly noticeable for Python because there is no other indication of scope like `{`/`}` pairs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Code fences are now implemented. See [Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#322000) on MSE for all the details.

Comment: Let there be rejoicing and dancing in the streets. This is great!

Comment: @Jeremy Yep: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: So happy that this has finally happened. It always seemed so weird, that the absolute core function of StackOverflow - code snippets within questions - was so poorly implemented, and incompatible with the standard everyone expects.