# Can we make syntax highlighting easier?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, syntax-highlighting

It seems as though often the syntax highlighter does not detect the language I'm working in.

When this happens, I try to be responsible and apply the manual highlighting comment: `<!-- language: NAME -->`.

However, it's hard for me to remember this syntax because it is *finicky*.

Consider the following examples of the highlighting comment with subtle changes in spacing:

`<!-- language: python -->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

`<!--language: python -->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

`<!-- language: python-->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

`<!--language:python-->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

`<!-- language:python -->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

`<!-- language:    python -->`

```
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

Since the foregoing doesn't display on Meta, I have an image:

[image: Of the six examples above, only the first results in correct highlighting. All others display as plain pre-formatted text.]

In all cases, the comments are detected as such, but in only some cases is highlighting applied as a result.

Is there a way to make this command less finicky and, hopefully, thereby easier to use?

Comment: Does this only apply to python or also other languages? If its only python maybe we can just get rid of that language :P

Comment: Any question about Python should be tagged [python].  That takes care of selecting the proper highlighting.

Comment: @HansPassant Unless it's also tagged with another, more popular, language tag, say because the question involved code from multiple languages.

Comment: @Servy, Surely no language is more popular than Python!

Comment: @Servy: Oddly enough, the other day I had to add lang-js hints to JS blocks on a question that was tagged [javascript] and [python], because they were being treated *as* Python code.

Comment: You would actually be able to display the syntax highlighting on meta without a screenshot if you used the Prettify language identifiers instead of the tag names (e.g. lang-py instead of python). The colors are much more subtle though.

Comment: @AndréKool: I assume this applies to other languages, though I have not tested it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Multiple languages could be present in a question or answer, so there's ambiguity. Regardless, I this, while helpful, dodges the central issue: the current setup makes it (needlessly?) difficult to specify highlighting.

Comment: is there somewhere a list of all supported syntax highlighted languages/codes. We could then make a bookmarklet that would add a simple select list that copies the right one in.

Comment: You’ve proven that there are a lot of white-space permutations possible, but, seriously, is `<!--` single-space `language:` single-space *name* single-space `-->` really so hard to remember? There is no space before the colon, but that’s the standard typesetting on computers anyway.

Comment: IMO SO should support the fenced code block style (i.e. `\`\`\`python\ncode goes here\n\`\`\``)

Comment: @Holger The only thing I sometimes forget is if it's `<!-- language: ... -->` or `<!-- lang: ... -->`. The reason why I sometimes make this mistake is because you should actually use `lang-py` in stead of `python`, so sometimes I accidentally write `<!-- lang: lang-py -->`. Bookmarking [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) helped a lot.

Comment: @JF Cf. [*Support CommonMark fenced code blocks*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288374/2751851) and [*Will CommonMark be adopted for SE?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957/242059) (Meta.SE).

Comment: @BoltClock The colors are the same to me.

Comment: When I need to highlight, I google "syntax highlight stackoverflow" which gets me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from which I inferred `language: python`. `language: lang-py` is not something I'd've guessed, especially with `language: c#` as an example.

Comment: @Tschallacka [Yes, the entire list of languages is available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I'd be for making a separate button with a keyboard shortcut that would open a popup dialog where you could select syntax highligting for the selected block. Languages used in the tags could have been listed on top of the list for example.

Answer (score 5):

If you use code fences, this is easy to remember.

Simply create the code fence and put the language right next to it:

````
```python
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```
````

Result:

```python
for i in range(10):
  print('hi')
```

Of course, it's not as easy as it could be (you can make a mistake typing the language), but it's a lot better than what we were limited to before code fences.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `\`\`\`python` tells the highlighter to look at the [[tag:python]] *tag* for a language hint, and does not specify the language directly. For that, use `\`\`\`lang-python`. This *usually* doesn't matter, since the language tags are in general well-kept, but it does matter for some, eg. [[tag:typescript]] (uses `lang-js` even though `lang-ts` exists).