# Why can't I format my code properly?

Tags: support, code-formatting, editor

I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111318/differences-in-using-list-returned-by-a-list-findall-in-a-foreach-loop-from-us/54111633#54111633) and realised that the formatting is very messed up.

> [image]

I tried adding four leading spaces on each line, the text is still formatted as normal text.

> [image]

I tried `<code>` and it looked weird (which is what it is currently).

One possible reason might be that I copied the text from a .docx file opened in Pages, and some of the formatting characters confused the editor?

Can someone help me fix it/tell me how to fix it?

Also, does this count as a bug of the editor?

Comment: _“I tried adding four leading spaces on each line”_ — show an example of what exactly you tried. Have you read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)?

Comment: There appear to be some weird invisible characters in the code

Comment: Just formatted your code using the newfangled code-fencing feature, and it seems to look fine.

Comment: @Xufox I have been on the site for years. Of course I have read that and know how to format my code. I think this is happening because I copied it from a .docx file, which possibly contains formatting characters, though I am not sure.

Comment: @yivi What's that? I have never heard of it.

Comment: @Sweeper: There were definitely some strange characters in the code. After removing them, everything works as expected.

Comment: Three backticks. Was implemented today, or yesterday. [Here you have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378734/1426539) the announcement.

Comment: @BDL But why should those characters break formatting? Is that by-design?

Comment: That code was littered with unicode 2028 LINE SEPARATOR characters, probably those caused it.

Comment: @yivi Wow! Finally three backticks on SO! YAY!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth so do you think this counts as a bug or by design?

Comment: @Sweeper: [That's how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1bK.png). I guess that line separators stop the code block (similar to how a normal newline would do). I'd call it "by design".

Comment: @Sweeper I'd say bug, these characters shouldn't really have any influence over how the code is formatted. Though a very localized, low-priority bug.

Comment: The weird invisible characters could be from copying code from [Skype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) chat. It is Unicode's "U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE". On disk it may be the sequence 0xC2 0xA0 (UTF-8), but in some editors (e.g. [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)) it is the code point that should be searched/replaced for (`\x{00A0}` in Notepad++, in regular expression mode).