# Should we make the {} button add ``` instead of four spaces?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor, formatting

I didn't know that the [three backticks code fence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288374/support-commonmark-fenced-code-blocks/378734#378734) feature was implemented until I asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378770/why-cant-i-format-my-code-properly).

This is a great new feature! I think the code block button in the editor (the `{}` button) should add three backticks as well, instead of the old four leading spaces syntax.

What I mean is this:

I have the text:

```
some code
some code line two
```

When I select that in the editor and press the code block button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>), this would happen:

````
```
some code
some code line two
```
````

instead of this:

```
    some code
    some code line two
```

Comment: [comment from balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks/322000#comment1054011_322000): *"As for the other thing, there are a bunch of places where indenting is recommended. Once code fences have been working for a bit, we may revisit which way of creating code blocks should be the recommended one."*

Comment: You don't mention any reason *why* you want this change or what advantages it would bring.

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense to have it insert a tab rather than 4 spaces...

Comment: @usr2564301 Aren't people supposed to view their question in the preview pane before posting?

Comment: Random arguments in favor of backticks: 1. less characters in the message when there is multiple lines of code; 2. allows to easily change the programming language syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Cœur As if people write 65536-character answers that often... About 2, I think people don't use manual syntax highlighting very often.

Comment: @user202729 it did happen _once_ (out of 60000+ posts edited), that I couldn't format a block of code properly because adding 4 spaces on each line was pushing the limit over 65536 characters. (in the end, I voted to close+delete the question as lacking MVCE)

Comment: Obviously people prefer `\`\`\`` upvotes this question and people prefer indent (or hate changes?) downvote this question, but... because adding `\`\`\`` is just as easy as select and Ctrl+K, why don't you just triple backtick manually and leave Ctrl+K for people who like indentation?

Comment: There's indeed so much broken python formatting on the main page. Typically function or class definitions don't get indented because the first line is left out of the code block. Or OP doesn't even code format, which leads to broken indentation. Making the code-format button inject triple backticks probably wouldn't help with this specifically, but indeed in [tag:python] code fences are a huge blessing. Also a lot of  people familiar with github syntax will try using triple backticks (I often see that both on main and in chat).

Comment: FWIW, I have to always use workarounds to get code copy+pasted in with the correct indentation. It's always been my biggest annoyance dealing with code on S.O., and has stopped me from doing needed edits on many occasions. I would prefer if `Indented == code` was deprecated and removed ASAP. It's unintuitive, problematic, and annoying. It wouldn't be too difficult or bug prone to properly change billions of posts, right? 

Comment: @Stargateur What about `~`?

Comment: @user202729 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/KB_France.svg/1000px-KB_France.svg.png "why don't you just triple backtick manually and leave Ctrl+K for people who like indentation?" because ` is painful to write on my keyboard. `What about `~`?` I don't understand why you ask that

Comment: @Stargateur (Because triple ~ works as well)

Comment: Related: [Code sample button to insert code fences with backticks by default](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328901/289905).

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/414860/change-the-code-block-button-from-inserting-indentation-to-triple-backticks?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a use case where three backticks are counterintuitive:

- If the code block is under a bullet point

  ```
  it needs to be indented by additional 4 spaces
  ```

  - and so on

    ```
    for each bullet level
    ```
- If I use backticks instead

```
The code won't be indented
```

- To achieve this,

  ```
  I need to indent it, too
  ```

This feature is undocumented, and if you only know backticks, you can't come to discover it 'cuz you wouldn't know why and how the leading space is significant for code formatting.

Comment: Might just be me... but indenting the backticks is far more intuitive than double indenting. To me, it's pretty clear that you're indenting the code block when you indent with backticks. Whereas without backticks, the indentation has two meanings: 1. Create a code block, then 2. Indent that created code block

Comment: @Rob When you use backticks and rendered indentation is wrong, you have no idea what is wrong and what to do. Most will probably do nothing, leaving us with tons of posts with broken structure. When you use indentation and it's displayed as regular text -- just like without indent, -- a logical thought is to try to add more indent. Backticks allow to write posts with broken structure while indentation doesn't.

Comment: Not sure I follow... If people are unaware of indentation, their post is going to be badly formatted regardless of which approach they use. If they *are* aware of indentation, then I disagree with the idea that 'you have no idea what is wrong and what to do'

Comment: @Rob If you use backticks without indent, the code will be formatted as code but the code block will be badly indented. You have no idea how to fix the indent, but also no motivation to look for solution 'cuz it's "good enough as it is". Indentation doesn't allow you to escape with that: with incorrect indent, code will not be formatted as code until you find a proper solution. So the backticks encourage problematic behavior and thus shall not be promoted as the primary way of formatting.

Comment: Indenting list items can be done with CTRL+K as well. if you have backtick formatting in a list but without indentation, CTRL+K indents it. So for code in lists, remapping CTRL+K to three backticks would make it harder to write code in lists (which in some cases is desired). Additionally, code fences are significantly easier to type (`\`\`\`\`\`\`` -> `\`\`\`|\`\`\`` -> <newline and paste/type>, compared to manually adding four spaces to each line)

Answer (score 18):

I'm in favor of this change because:

- This allows better copy-paste (more compatible with other systems)
- This reduces the number of wasted space (Character length of the answer, also octet space, just imagine how much space this style of indentation is taking on SO server)
- Selecting a specific language is far easier (`<!-- language: none -->` vs ```` ```none ````)

Comment: Waste space? In the editor? That may be a good point, but normally code line length are not that long anyway. About better copy paste: actually GitHub support 4-space indentation as well.

Comment: @user202729 I don't have stats but " GitHub support 4-space indentation as well" is not a good point. The question is how many system support "markdown style" vs indentation style. And I think the answer is a lot more support markdown. Also, when copy paste from source, you copy useless space and must remove them somehow, generally shift+tab. This is not needed with markdown style.

Comment: With triple backtick (if that's what you mean with "Markdown style") you must remove useless indentation as well, otherwise the code in the question is over-indented and that looks bad.

Comment: Actually, the only code block style ["original"](http://www.wilfred.me.uk/blog/2012/07/30/why-markdown-is-not-my-favourite-language/) Markdown supported is indentation. https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode

Comment: @Stargateur That blog post is by the person who originally came up with Markdown; go to the Main tab and find the download from 2004 ([when Markdown was introduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)). John Gruber has been working on the internet for many, many years.

Comment: @Stargateur the first link (on the word "original") is by Wilfred Hughes, but the second link, to daringfireball.net, is John Gruber's website.

Comment: I think I miss understood what you tell me. My bad @user202729

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this proposal.
My arguments are as follows:

- New users may misunderstand how to use 4 spaces style and don't realize that the indentation matters. This results in only the first line of code being displayed as code, or the last line getting ignored, etc.
- When the question gets edited, the editor often simply adds ```` ``` ```` to define code fences explicitly. But it turns into another awkward thing, lots of spaces in every line of code, e.g.:
  [image]
- You can see code fences clearly and exactly, when it **BEGINS** with `, **ENDS** with` , but not 4 spaces in every line ...
- You can set programming language easily. You just need to write it after the first ```. As far as 4 spaces style is concerned, I don't know for sure whether you can select a language there, at all! But even if it is possible, it must be more complicated.

Comment: `<!-- language: blahblahblah -->`

Comment: @LoganDevine That syntax is [officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#how-do-i-use-syntax-highlighting) for indented code blocks, and may be removed in the future; using it is generally discouraged.